# Excel, creating a dynamic Data Validation dropdown by condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large list of food info in an Excel sheet. For example, two columns:

```
Apples Fruit
Beets Vegetable
Spinach Vegetable
Cheese Dairy
```

I have another sheet with a data validation dropdown that allows you to choose foods from the food info sheet. However, I'd like to be able to narrow the search fields by allowing the user to also select a category that informs the dropdown.

For example, two columns (user enters "Fruit" on the left column, perhaps from a dropdown that has items like Fruit, Vegetable, Dairy, etc):

```
Fruit (dropdown that contains fruit items from the food info sheet)
```

I don't know how to make the Data Validation field say "select all food names (from the food info sheet) where the category info (on the food info sheet) equals the category designated by the user (on the sheet with the dropdowns)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say *Sheet2* is like:

[image]

In *Sheet1* cell **A1** put the usual Data Validation including the values *Fruit, Vegetables,Dairy*
Then put the following event macro in the *Sheet1* worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A1 As Range, B1 As Range, sDV As String
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    Set A1 = Range("A1")
    Set B1 = Range("B1")

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, A1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    v = A1.Value
    sDV = ""
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To N
            If v = .Cells(i, "B").Value Then
                sDV = sDV & "," & .Cells(i, "A").Value
            End If
        Next i
        sDV = Mid(sDV, 2)
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With B1.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=sDV
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Now whenever you select a category in cell **A1,** the proper DV will be setup for cell **B1.**

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: So basically this is just iterating through the items on sheet2 and making a custom list to be inputted into the data validation? Will this work for multiple input fields? For example if one dropdown is chosen for fruits and the next dropdown is chosen for veggies and the third one is chosen for veggies, it'll all still hold firm?

Comment: Yes.........You can even add categories if you manually add the category to the **A1 DV** and then put the additional records into *Sheet2* ....... **Be sure to follow my instructions for installing the macro**

Comment: I think I need to edit the hard-coded A1 B1 figures to the row the user currently has selected. Can this be done with ActiveCell?

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Changed the code to Set A1 = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row) and Set B1 = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row)

Comment: Just remember that the **A1-** equivalent needs to be setup manually with the category **DV**

Comment: I have the dropdowns in column A set to data validation on a preset list of categories